# Graphic symbols not showing in Consolas font in Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10

Tags: utf-8, fonts, windows-10, sublimetext3, consolas

Some graphic symbols not showing in Consolas font in Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10.

For example: ◀

Other UTF-8 extended glyphs, like ñ, áéíóú works.

Screencap:

[image: Triangle not showing in Consolas Font]

The triangle shows in all other fonts.

I checked the versión of my Consoles font files and all them are the latests.

The triangle shows in Consolas in any other text editor installed in the system.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can verify in charmap.exe that Consolas doesn't have a glyph for "◀" (U+25C0). In this case, an edit control that uses Uniscribe will select an appropriate fallback font such as Segoe UI Symbol. At a low level, the edit control is calling functions such as [`ScriptItemize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368556), [`ScriptShape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368564), and [`ScriptTextOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368795).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

I set this options to:

```
    "font_options": ["directwrite"],
    "theme_font_options": ["directwrite"],
```

And now the font displays as it should.

My ST3 version is 3143 tho. No update available yet in the stable channel.

Comment: DirectWrite also uses a fallback font in this case, e.g. see [`IDWriteFontFallback::MapCharacters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280480). It's not the case that selecting "Consolas" means all rendered glyphs will be from that font. Most fonts only support a fraction of Unicode. [Consolas 5.32](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1924) has 2735 glyphs.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand why lines with this chars does not align well for a monospace font.But this fix makes the code show the expected pictures instead of the ugly square thing, so it is valid for me. :)